# PHP Form Validation Errors Not Showing

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

Practicing on a simple PHP form and can't figure out why the validation error messages are not appearing when fields aren't filled in or selected. Can anyone spot what might be causing the $errors not to show? I can't tell if the $errors array is functioning correctly. I'd like for each error message to pop up beneath the fields that aren't completed, and for the fields to not clear out if, say, there is only one incomplete form.

Thanks for any assistance.

```
<?php 

//DEFINE VARIABLES

$errors = array();
$success = false;
$name = $nameErr = $origin = $dob = $sex = $destination = null;
$destination_options = array("choose" => "--Please Choose Your Destination--", "mercury" => "Mercury", "venus" => "Venus", "moon" => "Moon", "jupiter" => "Jupiter", "saturn" => "Saturn", "uranus" => "Uranus", "neptune" => "Neptune", "pluto" => "Pluto", "ub313" => "2003 UB313");
$trip = $purpose = $arrest = $arrest_reason = $terrorist = $fears = $insurance = $terms = null;


// Check if form was submitted

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['origin']) && isset($_POST['dob']) && isset($_POST['sex']) && isset($_POST['destination']) && isset($_POST['trip']) && isset($_POST['purpose']) && isset($_POST['arrest']) && isset($_POST['arrest_reason']) && isset($_POST['terrorist']) && isset($_POST['fears']) && isset($_POST['insurance']) && isset($_POST['terms'])) {

    //VALIDATE INPUTS

    if (empty($_POST['name']))
        $errors['name'] = "Please enter your name.";
    else
        $name = $_POST['name'];
    if (empty($_POST['origin']))
        $errors['origin'] = "Please enter your country of origin.";
    else 
        $origin = $_POST['origin'];
    if (empty($_POST['dob']) && is_numeric($_POST['dob']))
        $errors['dob'] = "Please enter a valid birth date.";
    else 
        $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    if (empty($_POST['sex']) && preg_match("/\b(M)\b/", $_POST['sex']) && preg_match("/\b(F)\b/", $_POST['sex']))
        $errors['sex'] = "Please provide your sex.";
    else
        $sex = $_POST['sex'];
    if (!array_key_exists($_POST['destination'], $destination_options))
        $errors['destination'] = "Please select a destination.";
    else 
        $destination = $_POST['destination'];
    if (empty($_POST['trip']))
        $errors['trip'] = "Please choose One Way or Round Trip travel.";
    else
        $trip = $_POST['trip'];
    if (empty($_POST['purpose']))
        $errors['purpose'] = "Please tell us why you\'re traveling.";
    else
        $purpose = $_POST['purpose'];
    if (empty($_POST['arrest']))
        $errors['arrest'] = "Please tell us if you were ever arrested.";
    else
        $arrest = $_POST['arrest'];
    if (empty($_POST['arrest_reason']) && $arrest = $_POST['arrest']=='yes')
        $errors['arrest_reason'] = "Please tell us why you were arrested.";
    else
        $arrest_reason = $_POST['arrest_reason'];
    if (empty($_POST['terrorist']))
        $errors['terrorist'] = "Come on now, tell us if you're a terrorist. We really need to know!";
    else
        $terrorist = $_POST['terrorist'];
    if (empty($_POST['terms']))
        $errors['terms'] = "You must agree to the terms & conditions before submitting.";

    // IF NO ERRORS

    if (!$errors) {
        $success = true;
    }
}


?>


<div id="container">
  <div id="intro">
      <img src="img/p_logo.svg" alt="logo" />

      <?php 

          // IF NO ERRORS AND FORM SUBMITS SUCCESSFULLY

          if ($success) {

              if ($_POST['arrest']=='no' && $_POST['terrorist']=='no' && $_POST['insurance']=='regular') {
                  echo "<p class='error'>THANK YOU! Your application is being processed.<br />Your estimated trip cost with REGULAR insurance is $40,000. <br />You will hear from a representative shortly to finalize the details. <br />Get ready to go to space!</p>";

              } else if ($_POST['arrest']=='no' && $_POST['terrorist']=='no' && $_POST['insurance']=='deluxe') {
                  echo "<p class='error'>THANK YOU! Your application is being processed.<br />Your estimated trip cost with DELUXE insurance is $50,000. <br />You will hear from a representative shortly to finalize the details. <br />Get ready to go to space!</p>";

              } else if ($_POST['arrest']=='no' && $_POST['terrorist']=='no' && $_POST['insurance']=='no') { 
                  echo "<p class='error'>THANK YOU! Your application is being processed and you will hear from a representative soon.<br />Get ready to go to space!</p>"; 
              }

              if ($_POST['arrest']=='yes' || $_POST['terrorist']=='yes')
                  echo "<p class='error'>BASED ON YOUR INFORMATION, YOU HAVE BEEN DEEMED A SECURITY RISK AND YOUR APPLICATION IS DENIED.<br />AN AGENT WILL REACH YOU SHORTLY.</p>";

              // CLEAR FIELDS   
              list($name, $origin, $dob, $sex, $destination, $trip, $purpose, $arrest, $arrest_reason, $terrorist, $fears, $insurance, $terms) = array(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

          }

      ?>


      <h1>Interplanetary Shuttle Registration</h1>
      <p>
          Please complete all fields. <br />Costs will be calculated and applicants accepted or rejected for travel based on input.<br />
          If approved, you will be contacted by a PlanetCo agent to complete the process.
      </p>      
  </div>

  <form action="space_trip_registration.php" method="POST">
      <fieldset>

          <legend>Basic Info</legend>
          <label for="name">Full Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="name" tabindex="1" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />
              <?php
                  if (isset($errors['name']))                                        
                      echo "<p class='error'>".$errors['name']."</p>";                  
              ?>


          <label for="origin">Country of Origin</label>
          <input type="text" id="origin" name="origin" tabindex="2" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($origin, ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />
              <?php
                  if (isset($errors['origin']))                                      
                      echo "<p class='error'>".$errors['origin']."</p>";                        
              ?>
          <br /><br />

          <label for="dob">Date of Birth</label>
          <input type="text" name="dob" maxlength="10" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" tabindex="3" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($dob, ENT_QUOTES);?>" />
              <?php
                  if (isset($errors['dob']))                                         
                      echo "<p class='error'>".$errors['dob']."</p>";
              ?>
          <label for="sex">Sex</label>
          <input type="text" name="sex" maxlength="1" placeholder="M/F" tabindex="4" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($sex, ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />
              <?php
                  if (isset($errors['sex']))                             
                      echo "<p class='error'>".$errors['sex']."</p>";                           
              ?>

          <br /><br />

          <legend>Desination</legend>
          <label for="destination">Destination</label>
          <select name="destination" id="destination" tabindex="5">
              <!-- <option selected="selected"> --Please Choose Your Destination-- </option> -->
              <?php 
                  foreach($destination_options as $key => $value) 
                      echo "<option value='" .$key. "'".($key == $destination ? " selected='selected'" : " ").">".htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES)."</option>"

              ?>
          </select>
              <?php
                  if (isset($errors['destination']))                                     
                      echo "<p class='error'>".$errors['destination']."</p>";                           
              ?>

          <br /><br />

          <label for="trip">Is This A One-Way or Round- Trip?</label>
          <br />
          <input type="radio" id="trip" name="trip" value="one" tabindex="6">One Way <input type="radio" id="trip" name="trip" value="round" tabindex="7">Round Trip
              <?php
                  if (isset($errors['trip']))                                        
                      echo "<p class='error'>".$errors['trip']."</p>";                          
              ?>
          <br /><br />
          <label for="purpose">Primary Reason for Traveling</label>
          <br />
          <textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="purpose" name="purpose" tabindex="8" <?php echo htmlspecialchars($purpose, ENT_QUOTES); ?> ></textarea>
              <?php
                  if (isset($errors['purpose']))                                     
                      echo "<p class='error'>".$errors['purpose']."</p>";                           
              ?>            
          <br /><br />

          <legend>Additional Info</legend>

          <label for="arrest">Have You Ever Been Arrested?</label>
          <input type="radio" name="arrest" value="yes">Yes <input type="radio" name="arrest" value="no" tabindex="9" >No
              <?php
                  if (isset($errors['arrest']))                                          
                      echo "<p class='error'>".$errors['arrest']."</p>";                            
              ?>
          <br />
          <label for="arrest_reason">If yes, why?</label>
          <input type="text" name="arrest_reason" tabindex="10" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($arrest_reason, ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />
              <?php
                  if (isset($errors['arrest_reason']))                                       
                      echo "<p class='error'>".$errors['arrest_reason']."</p>";                         
              ?>
          <br /><br />
          <label for="terrorist">Are you a terrorist?</label>
          <input type="radio" name="terrorist" value="yes" tabindex="11">Yes <input type="radio" name="terrorist" value="no" tabindex="12">No
              <?php
                  if (isset($errors['terrorist']))                                   
                      echo "<p class='error'>".$errors['terrorist']."</p>";                         
              ?>
          <br /><br />

          <!-- FEARS CHECKBOXES -->

          <label for="fears">What Do You Fear? <span class="italic finePrint">(Check all that apply)</span></label><br />
          <label for="aliens"><input type="checkbox" id="aliens" name="fears" value="aliens" tabindex="13">Aliens</label>
          <label for="zero_gravity"><input type="checkbox" id="zero_graviy" name="fears" value="zero_gravity" tabindex="14">Zero Gravity</label>
          <label for="solar_flares"><input type="checkbox" id="solar_flares" name="fears" value="solar_flares" tabindex="15">Solar Flares</label>
          <br />
          <label for="vast_space"><input type="checkbox" id="vast_space" name="fears" value="vast_space" tabindex="16">Vast Infinite Space</label>
          <label for="black_holes"><input type="checkbox" id="black_holes" name="fears" value="black_holes" tabindex="17">Black Holes</label>
          <label for="wormholes"><input type="checkbox" id="wormholes" name="fears" value="wormholes" tabindex="18">Wormholes</label>
          <br />
          <label for="airlock"><input type="checkbox" id="airlock" name="fears" value="airlock" tabindex="19">Getting accidentally blown out of an airlock by a malicious, self-aware computer</label> <br />
          <label for="interstellar"><input type="checkbox" id="interstellar" name="fears" value="interstellar" tabindex="20">Getting lost in space-time like in <span class="italic">Interstellar</span></label>
              <?php
                  if (isset($errors['fears']))                                   
                      echo "<p class='error'>".$errors['fears']."</p>";
              ?>
          <br /><br />

          <!-- END FEARS CHECKBOXES --> 

          <legend>Insurance</legend>
          <p>Trip insurance is offered in two packages: Deluxe and Regular.<br /><span class="italic finePrint">Insurance does not cover cases of catastrophic malfunction, alien abduction, or discharge from airlock by a malicious, self-aware computer.</span></p>
          <label for="insurance">Purchase Trip Insurance</label>
          <label for="no"><input type="radio" id="no" name="insurance" value="no" checked="checked" tabindex="21">No</label>
          <label for="regular"><input type="radio" id="regular" name="insurance" value="regular" tabindex="22">Regular <span class="italic finePrint">(add $10,000)</span></label>
          <label for="deluxe"><input type="radio" id="deluxe" name="insurance" value="deluxe" tabindex="23">Deluxe <span class="italic finePrint">(add $20,000)</span></label>
          <br /><br />

          <!-- FINAL SUBMIT SECTION -->

          <legend>Terms and Conditions</legend>
          <label for="terms"><input type="checkbox" id="terms" name="terms" value="terms" tabindex="24">I agree to the <a href="#" id='conditions'  title="Terms and Conditions">terms and conditions</a> set by PlanetCo.</label>
              <?php
                  if (isset($errors['terms']))                                   
                      echo "<p class='error'>".$errors['terms']."</p>"; 
              ?>
          <br /><br />

          <div class="buttonDiv">
              <button type="submit" tabindex="25">APPLY</button>
          </div>

      </fieldset>
  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep your validation code out of if condition. In your if condition you are already checking if all fields are set and if all your fields are set there is no error to show. So move your validation code before the if condition starts.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful -- didn't totally solved my problem (tweaking some more code undid any gains), but put me more on the right track. It looks like a big factor was the checkboxes and radios not being set if unchecked. Haven't completely solved the problem, but getting there.

Answer (score 0):

The checkboxes in POST only appears it has value.

```
<?php 
//DEFINE VARIABLES

$errors = array();
$success = false;
$name = $nameErr = $origin = $dob = $sex = $destination = null;
$destination_options = array("choose" => "--Please Choose Your Destination--", "mercury" => "Mercury", "venus" => "Venus", "moon" => "Moon", "jupiter" => "Jupiter", "saturn" => "Saturn", "uranus" => "Uranus", "neptune" => "Neptune", "pluto" => "Pluto", "ub313" => "2003 UB313");
$trip = $purpose = $arrest = $arrest_reason = $terrorist = $fears = $insurance = $terms = null;


// Check if form was submitted

if (isset($_POST['submitBtn'])) {

    //VALIDATE INPUTS

    if (empty($_POST['name']))
        $errors['name'] = "Please enter your name.";
    else
        $name = $_POST['name'];
    if (empty($_POST['origin']))
        $errors['origin'] = "Please enter your country of origin.";
    else 
        $origin = $_POST['origin'];
    if (empty($_POST['dob']) && is_numeric($_POST['dob']))
        $errors['dob'] = "Please enter a valid birth date.";
    else 
        $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    if (empty($_POST['sex']) && preg_match("/\b(M)\b/", $_POST['sex']) && preg_match("/\b(F)\b/", $_POST['sex']))
        $errors['sex'] = "Please provide your sex.";
    else
        $sex = $_POST['sex'];
    if (!array_key_exists($_POST['destination'], $destination_options))
        $errors['destination'] = "Please select a destination.";
    else 
        $destination = $_POST['destination'];
    if (empty($_POST['trip']))
        $errors['trip'] = "Please choose One Way or Round Trip travel.";
    else
        $trip = $_POST['trip'];
    if (empty($_POST['purpose']))
        $errors['purpose'] = "Please tell us why you\'re traveling.";
    else
        $purpose = $_POST['purpose'];
    if (empty($_POST['arrest']))
        $errors['arrest'] = "Please tell us if you were ever arrested.";
    else
        $arrest = $_POST['arrest'];
    if (empty($_POST['arrest_reason']) && (isset($arrest) && $arrest=='yes'))
        $errors['arrest_reason'] = "Please tell us why you were arrested.";
    else
        $arrest_reason = $_POST['arrest_reason'];
    if (empty($_POST['terrorist']))
        $errors['terrorist'] = "Come on now, tell us if you're a terrorist. We really need to know!";
    else
        $terrorist = $_POST['terrorist'];
    if (empty($_POST['terms']))
        $errors['terms'] = "You must agree to the terms & conditions before submitting.";

    // IF NO ERRORS

    if (!$errors) {
        $success = true;
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,300,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <title>Interplanetary Travel Registration</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        html {margin:0; padding:0; background-color:#eeeeee; font-family:'Roboto',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;}
        #container {width:98%; min-width:480px; max-width:1000px; margin:0 auto;}
        #intro {text-align:center; text-transform:uppercase;}
        legend {font-weight:700; text-transform:uppercase;}
        input {padding:0.4rem; border:1px solid #cccccc; border-radius:2px;}
        textarea {padding:0.5rem; border:1px solid #cccccc; border-radius:2px;}
        span.italic {font-style:italic;}
        .finePrint {font-size:0.8rem;}
        button {padding:0.7rem;cursor: pointer;}
        .buttonDiv {margin:0 auto; width:60px; text-align:center;}
        .error {color:#be1e2d; font-weight:700}
    </style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

    <div id="intro">
        <img src="img/p_logo.svg" alt="logo" />

        <?php 

            // IF NO ERRORS AND FORM SUBMITS SUCCESSFULLY

            if ($success) {

                if ($_POST['arrest']=='no' && $_POST['terrorist']=='no' && $_POST['insurance']=='regular') {
                    echo "<p class='error'>THANK YOU! Your application is being processed.<br />Your estimated trip cost with REGULAR insurance is $40,000. <br />You will hear from a representative shortly to finalize the details. <br />Get ready to go to space!</p>";

                } else if ($_POST['arrest']=='no' && $_POST['terrorist']=='no' && $_POST['insurance']=='deluxe') {
                    echo "<p class='error'>THANK YOU! Your application is being processed.<br />Your estimated trip cost with DELUXE insurance is $50,000. <br />You will hear from a representative shortly to finalize the details. <br />Get ready to go to space!</p>";

                } else if ($_POST['arrest']=='no' && $_POST['terrorist']=='no' && $_POST['insurance']=='no') { 
                    echo "<p class='error'>THANK YOU! Your application is being processed and you will hear from a representative soon.<br />Get ready to go to space!</p>"; 
                }

                if ($_POST['arrest']=='yes' || $_POST['terrorist']=='yes')
                    echo "<p class='error'>BASED ON YOUR INFORMATION, YOU HAVE BEEN DEEMED A SECURITY RISK AND YOUR APPLICATION IS DENIED.<br />AN AGENT WILL REACH YOU SHORTLY.</p>";

                // CLEAR FIELDS 
                list($name, $origin, $dob, $sex, $destination, $trip, $purpose, $arrest, $arrest_reason, $terrorist, $fears, $insurance, $terms) = array(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

            }

        ?>


        <h1>Interplanetary Shuttle Registration</h1>
        <p>
            Please complete all fields. <br />Costs will be calculated and applicants accepted or rejected for travel based on input.<br />
            If approved, you will be contacted by a PlanetCo agent to complete the process.
        </p>        
    </div>

    <form action="space_trip_registration.php" method="POST">
        <fieldset>

            <legend>Basic Info</legend>
            <label for="name">Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" tabindex="1" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />
                <?php
                    if (isset($errors['name']))                                      
                        echo "<p class='error'>".$errors['name']."</p>";                    
                ?>


            <label for="origin">Country of Origin</label>
            <input type="text" id="origin" name="origin" tabindex="2" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($origin, ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />
                <?php
                    if (isset($errors['origin']))                                    
                        echo "<p class='error'>".$errors['origin']."</p>";                      
                ?>
            <br /><br />

            <label for="dob">Date of Birth</label>
            <input type="text" name="dob" maxlength="10" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" tabindex="3" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($dob, ENT_QUOTES);?>" />
                <?php
                    if (isset($errors['dob']))                                       
                        echo "<p class='error'>".$errors['dob']."</p>";
                ?>
            <label for="sex">Sex</label>
            <input type="text" name="sex" maxlength="1" placeholder="M/F" tabindex="4" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($sex, ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />
                <?php
                    if (isset($errors['sex']))                           
                        echo "<p class='error'>".$errors['sex']."</p>";                         
                ?>

            <br /><br />

            <legend>Desination</legend>
            <label for="destination">Destination</label>
            <select name="destination" id="destination" tabindex="5">
                <!-- <option selected="selected"> --Please Choose Your Destination-- </option> -->
                <?php 
                    foreach($destination_options as $key => $value) 
                        echo "<option value='" .$key. "'".($key == $destination ? " selected='selected'" : " ").">".htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES)."</option>"

                ?>
            </select>
                <?php
                    if (isset($errors['destination']))                                   
                        echo "<p class='error'>".$errors['destination']."</p>";                         
                ?>

            <br /><br />

            <label for="trip">Is This A One-Way or Round- Trip?</label>
            <br />
            <input type="radio" id="trip" name="trip" value="one" tabindex="6">One Way <input type="radio" id="trip" name="trip" value="round" tabindex="7">Round Trip
                <?php
                    if (isset($errors['trip']))                                          
                        echo "<p class='error'>".$errors['trip']."</p>";                            
                ?>
            <br /><br />
            <label for="purpose">Primary Reason for Traveling</label>
            <br />
            <textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="purpose" name="purpose" tabindex="8" <?php echo htmlspecialchars($purpose, ENT_QUOTES); ?> ></textarea>
                <?php
                    if (isset($errors['purpose']))                                   
                        echo "<p class='error'>".$errors['purpose']."</p>";                         
                ?>          
            <br /><br />

            <legend>Additional Info</legend>

            <label for="arrest">Have You Ever Been Arrested?</label>
            <input type="radio" name="arrest" value="yes">Yes <input type="radio" name="arrest" value="no" tabindex="9" >No
                <?php
                    if (isset($errors['arrest']))                                        
                        echo "<p class='error'>".$errors['arrest']."</p>";                          
                ?>
            <br />
            <label for="arrest_reason">If yes, why?</label>
            <input type="text" name="arrest_reason" tabindex="10" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($arrest_reason, ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />
                <?php
                    if (isset($errors['arrest_reason']))                                         
                        echo "<p class='error'>".$errors['arrest_reason']."</p>";                           
                ?>
            <br /><br />
            <label for="terrorist">Are you a terrorist?</label>
            <input type="radio" name="terrorist" value="yes" tabindex="11">Yes <input type="radio" name="terrorist" value="no" tabindex="12">No
                <?php
                    if (isset($errors['terrorist']))                                     
                        echo "<p class='error'>".$errors['terrorist']."</p>";                           
                ?>
            <br /><br />

            <!-- FEARS CHECKBOXES -->

            <label for="fears">What Do You Fear? <span class="italic finePrint">(Check all that apply)</span></label><br />
            <label for="aliens"><input type="checkbox" id="aliens" name="fears" value="aliens" tabindex="13">Aliens</label>
            <label for="zero_gravity"><input type="checkbox" id="zero_graviy" name="fears" value="zero_gravity" tabindex="14">Zero Gravity</label>
            <label for="solar_flares"><input type="checkbox" id="solar_flares" name="fears" value="solar_flares" tabindex="15">Solar Flares</label>
            <br />
            <label for="vast_space"><input type="checkbox" id="vast_space" name="fears" value="vast_space" tabindex="16">Vast Infinite Space</label>
            <label for="black_holes"><input type="checkbox" id="black_holes" name="fears" value="black_holes" tabindex="17">Black Holes</label>
            <label for="wormholes"><input type="checkbox" id="wormholes" name="fears" value="wormholes" tabindex="18">Wormholes</label>
            <br />
            <label for="airlock"><input type="checkbox" id="airlock" name="fears" value="airlock" tabindex="19">Getting accidentally blown out of an airlock by a malicious, self-aware computer</label> <br />
            <label for="interstellar"><input type="checkbox" id="interstellar" name="fears" value="interstellar" tabindex="20">Getting lost in space-time like in <span class="italic">Interstellar</span></label>
                <?php
                    if (isset($errors['fears']))                                     
                        echo "<p class='error'>".$errors['fears']."</p>";
                ?>
            <br /><br />

            <!-- END FEARS CHECKBOXES --> 

            <legend>Insurance</legend>
            <p>Trip insurance is offered in two packages: Deluxe and Regular.<br /><span class="italic finePrint">Insurance does not cover cases of catastrophic malfunction, alien abduction, or discharge from airlock by a malicious, self-aware computer.</span></p>
            <label for="insurance">Purchase Trip Insurance</label>
            <label for="no"><input type="radio" id="no" name="insurance" value="no" checked="checked" tabindex="21">No</label>
            <label for="regular"><input type="radio" id="regular" name="insurance" value="regular" tabindex="22">Regular <span class="italic finePrint">(add $10,000)</span></label>
            <label for="deluxe"><input type="radio" id="deluxe" name="insurance" value="deluxe" tabindex="23">Deluxe <span class="italic finePrint">(add $20,000)</span></label>
            <br /><br />

            <!-- FINAL SUBMIT SECTION -->

            <legend>Terms and Conditions</legend>
            <label for="terms"><input type="checkbox" id="terms" name="terms" value="terms" tabindex="24">I agree to the <a href="#" id='conditions'  title="Terms and Conditions">terms and conditions</a> set by PlanetCo.</label>
                <?php
                    if (isset($errors['terms']))                                     
                        echo "<p class='error'>".$errors['terms']."</p>";   
                ?>
            <br /><br />

            <div class="buttonDiv">
                <button type="submit" name="submitBtn" tabindex="25">APPLY</button>
            </div>

        </fieldset>
    </form>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('conditions').onclick=function(){
        alert("TERMS & CONDITIONS: It's space, dude. We're gonna do our best, but you travel at your own risk. It's like, how the hell can we do anything about aliens, right?");
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```